# In Scala, can I use the same name for arguments and class fields

Tags: java, scala

In Java I usually call the argument of the setter with the same name as the field

```
public void setA(int a){
    this.a = a;
}
```

The reason is that later the IDE will show `a` as the param name, so it's better documented.

How do I do the same in Scala?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to. When you create a Scala class:

```
class A(val a: Int)
```

You get an accessor for 'free'. If you declare the argument as a `var` you get a setter as well. So, to answer your question: arguments already are class fields.

```
val myA = new A(42)
myA.a  // 42

class B(var b: Int)
val myB = new B(42)
myB.b  // 42
myB.b = 43
myB.b  // 43
```

The `getXXX` / `setXXX` convention of the java beans does not apply to Scala (which is sometimes an issue when trying to use a Java library in Scala).

Comment: how do override the getters and the setters then?

Comment: so basically there's no way, and you have to use a naming convention... mmmmh

Comment: @gotch4 There is a way: `def age_= (value:Int):Unit = _age = value` here you are defining the setter and you can put whatever code you want in it. How is it more a naming convention than `setXYZ/getXYZ`? Feel free to accept the answer when you are ready :)

Answer (score 1):

Java has four namespaces (iirc), Scala has two. You cannot do that, though see the other answer as to why that might not be a problem.